# Skype: Install Latest Version Notification

Tags: apt, skype, notification

In Skype notifications I have the following :

'A new update is available. Install the latest version via your package manager, then restart Skype'.

I have done the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux
```

And the notification still persists.

I decided to completely remove Skype and install it again:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skypeforlinux
```

I reinstalled Skype like so:

```
sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

The notification still persists.

I removed Skype again and downloaded it via the Ubuntu Software Store GUI, I am still getting the notification.

I downloaded it directly from the Skype Web page, the 'Skype for Linux DEB' package, and I still get the same notification.

I deleted cache for good measure also.

My system states:

```
skypeforlinux is already the newest version (8.61.0.95)

0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 16 not to upgrade.
```

However, I am still getting a notification within the application that an update is available. I have quit and restarted Skype numerous times. As well as carried out a system reboot several times.

Please could someone explain to me why this notification persists, and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: It is annoying but I think that there is a new MS Windows version. The new version for Linux will take some time. Meanwhile, ignore, endure :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install a package called `alien`. It converts `.rpm` files to `.deb` files.

   ```
   apt-get install alien
   ```
2. Download the last version `skypeforlinux_8.62.0.83-1.x86_64.rpm` from https://repo.skype.com/rpm/stable/
3. Convert this `.rpm` package to a `.deb` package with:

   ```
   alien skypeforlinux_8.62.0.83-1.x86_64.rpm
   ```
4. Install the resulting `.deb` package with:

   ```
   dpkg -i skypeforlinux_8.62.0.83-2_amd64.deb
   ```